# How to check if 2 consecutive values in a string are characters in another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to check if 2 consecutive values in a string are characters (minus 5 operators I pre-determined). I tried doing this:

```
test = "abcdefghijklmnop"

bad = "abfj"

for i in test:
    if i in bad and i+1 in bad:
        print("it works")
```

with no luck. Is there anyway to get the next index of a string inside of a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your desired output from the data in your question?

Comment: @jpp I would like that to print True. So if any two consecutive characters in test are also in bad, you return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` isn't the *index*, it's the actual *character*. That's why you can just write `i in bad` instead of `test[i] in bad`.

If you want the index as well as the character, use `enumerate`, like this:

```
for idx, ch in enumerate(test):
    if ch in bad and test[idx+1] in bad:
```

Or just use the index for both:

```
for idx in range(len(test)):
    if test[idx] in bad and test[idx+1] in bad:
```

Also, notice that whichever way you do this, you're going to have a bug when you reach the last character—you're going to try to check the next character, but there *is* no next character.

---

If you want to think a bit more abstractly, the `pairwise` function in  [th recipes in the `itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) (or you can `pip install` either `toolz` or `more-itertools`; I think they both have it) will let you loop over adjacent pairs of *anything*. So:

```
for current_char, next_char in pairwise(test):
    if current_char in bad and next_char in bad:
```

Or maybe this is a bit easier to understand, if less flexible:

```
for current_char, next_char in zip(test, test[1:]):
    if current_char in bad and next_char in bad:
```

---

Here's another trick that lets you avoid having to do two separate tests, if you understand the idea of set intersection:

```
bad = set(bad)

for idx in range(len(test)):
    if bad.intersection(test[idx:idx+2]):
```

You still need to deal with the "last one" problem—you'll get an incorrect test instead of an exception, but it's still wrong.

You can also combine this with `pairwise`.

Comment: You could also do `cur_char, next_char in zip(test, test[1:])` without any `itertools`. Edit: looks like the other answer beat me to it

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah, but `pairwise` works on any iterable, and only holds an extra copy of one element at a time instead of the whole sequence. But maybe it's worth mentioning.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! I'm just so used to languages like C# or Java so not having a traditional for loop throws me off a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are only trying to check whether two consecutive characters of `test` match in `bad`(not interested in which two) you can do

```
>>> any("".join([i,j]) in bad for i,j in zip(test,test[1:]))
>>> True
```

If you want which two characters match and which of them don't:

```
>>> [("".join([i,j]) in bad,"".join([i,j])) for i,j in zip(test,test[1:])]
>>> [(True, 'ab'), (False, 'bc'), (False, 'cd'), (False, 'de'), (False, 'ef'), (False, 'fg'), (False, 'gh'), (False, 'hi'), (False, 'ij'), (False, 'jk'), (False, 'kl'), (False, 'lm'), (False, 'mn'), (False, 'no'), (False, 'op')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression with `zip` for this.

The benefit of using a generator expression versus list comprehension is you do not have to iterate the entire string.

```
test = "abcdefghijklmnop"
bad = "abfj"
bad_set = set(bad)

res = ((i in bad_set) and (j in bad_set) for i, j in zip(test, test[1:]))

for k in res:
    if k:
        print(k)
        break

# True
```

Comment: You don't have to iterate the entire string with an explicit `for` loop either; you can `break` or `return` as soon as you find whatever you were looking for. And since your generator is driven by basically the same `for` loop, it will or won't iterate the entire string in the same way.

Comment: Well, there is a difference versus list comprehension.. If I used a list comprehension instead of a generator expression, I would clearly be calculating every Boolean value (not necessary). With explicit loops containing the logic, as in your answer, I agree.

Comment: If I returned when I found the 2 consecutive characters, would that actually be iterating over the entire string? Worst case would be the string not having 2 consecutive characters and that would be the only time it iterated all the way through, right?

Comment: You are correct. This is what `break` does.. if you reach `True` you break the loop. Worst case is you get to the end of the string and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

with range method in one line:

```
test = "abcdefghijklmnop"

bad = "abfj"


print([("true",test[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(test),1) if test[i:i+2] in bad])
```

With recursive approach:

```
test = "abcdefghijklmnop"

bad = "abfj"


def recursive_approach(test1):
    print(test1)
    if not test1:
        return 0
    else:
        if test1[:2] in bad:
            print('True', test1[:2])
        return recursive_approach(test1[1:])
print(recursive_approach(test))
```

Answer (score -1):

the i in that loop is a string,therefor you can't use it as an index
change this part of the code to this:

```
for i in range(0,len(test)):
    while(i+1<len(test)):
         if test[i] in bad and test[i+1] in bad:
            print("it works")
```